# Calculating Rotor Inertia or Mechanical Time Constant for BLDC Motor from Published Specs Only

Tags: brushless-dc-motor, brushed-dc-motor, rotor

TLDR - Is there any way of calculating the Mechancial Time Constant and/or Rotor Inertia and/or Run-Up Time based soley on the specs provided on this [motor](https://product.mabuchi-motor.com/detail.html?id=119)

My end goal in asking this question is to correctly size an onboard fuse for a product that I am designing. My caveat: I am not any type of engineer and I am very new to figuring out electronics.

To be as thorough as possible, I am trying to ensure that not only do I size the fuse correctly for normal operation, but to take the I^2T ratings and the Pulse Cycle Withstand ratings into account.

My specific problem at the moment is trying to calculate the duration of the inrush current. The product will need to deal with varying amounts of "Additional Load" at startup.

Amongst other sources, I am trying to use the formulas on Page four (4) this Maxon [guide](https://www.maxongroup.com/medias/sys_master/8815460712478.pdf?attachment=true)

The results I am trying to calculate are for the Mechanical Time Constant, and from there, the Maximum Angular Acceleration and Run-Up Time. I believe these results will allow me to simulate the inrush current duration.

Until something better comes along, I am considering using a Mabuchi [RS-555VC-3754](https://product.mabuchi-motor.com/detail.html?id=119) 
Unfortunately, they don't provide all of the specifications that other (more expensive) manufacturers do - or at least I haven't been able to find them.

So my main question is;

**Is there any way of calculating any or all of these amounts based on the specs provided by Mabuchi?**

Follow up questions:

-Is there another way to calculate the inrush current duration in order to calculate the I^2T value?

-Do you know if Mabuchi publish full specs such as a company like Faulhaber does (example [here](https://www.micromo.com/media/pdfs/1624_S_DFF.pdf)

Apologies in advance if I have rambled/asked something ignorant/not been clear.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to calculate rotor inertia from those specs. You could estimate that it is comparable to a more expensive motor with similar dimensions and specifications. There may be retail sellers of Mabuchi motors that publish more complete specs.